# Java: Protecting an object from being accessed by multiple threads

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, race-condition, synchronized

I have an OpenGL ES 2.0 App.  Within it, I have a class which contains a array of another type of object like so (this is simplified for the question):

```
public class StoreList(){

thisList StoreItems[];

    public StoreList(int nuberOfItems){

        thisList = StoreItems[numberOfItems];

    }

}
```

Initially, I populate the list and then at certain points during the app (when the user is in the 'store' scene), it's possible for new items to be added into the list, so, for example, the list could look something like this:

```
Before              After inserting object 'Fish' into index 1

Index 0  - Dog      Index 0 - Dog
Index 1  - Fox      Index 1 - Fish
Index 2  - Bird     Index 2 - Fox
Index 3  - Snake    Index 3 - Bird
                    Index 4 - Snake
```

Now, this list is iterated through for various reasons.  For example, for rendering, for updating their positions etc.

The problem I have is that, my app uses 2 threads - The GL Rendering thread, and the Main/UI thread.

When the user performs a certain action, the UI thread calls an 'insertObject' method which inserts an extra item as detailed above.  However the rendering thread is happily doing it's thing and if it was rendering the object at index 1 at the same time 'insertObject' was called, then it starts to cause problems (each object in the list has a different number of openGL quads to draw and the number to draw is contained in a variable in the object itself), so if the original object at index 1 had 5 quads, and the new object only has 4, then it starts to attempt to draw a 5th quad and we get all manner of issues (index out of bounds for example).

The render method, updateLogic method and the onTouchEvent methods are all declared as synchronized, but I'm still getting the issue.

I'm not really sure how to go about ensuring the this object (the instance of StoreList and everything within it and it's 'thisList' array) can only be updated from one thread at a time.

The questions that I've seen relating to concurrency issues have all been about protecting a method from being called by multiple threads and not objects, so I'm a little confused.

Would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Perhaps a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) would work better for you?

Comment: Easiest way: protect the list by a [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). Each method that wants to read or write the list needs to acquire the `Lock` first. Slightly more complicated: try using [`@synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html). As long as there are no blocking constructs used within `@synchronized` (like `wait()`), this should do the job.

Comment: Thanks @Turing85, Do you mean using a synchronized block on all code that will read/write from/to the list? (Using the list itself as the lock object?) I'm just wondering could I simply declare any method that reads/writes to the list as synchronized?  I've just done that and so far no crashes (after about 30 tests).  Also I'm not sure what you mean re '@synchronized'.  Could you provide an example? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't know about *CopyOnWriteArrayList* @RealSkeptic, interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use synchronized block on StoreItems instead of synchronizing the insert/update methods. The synchronized block would guarantee that only one thread may execute insert code block, or any other code block(say update) which is synchronized on the same object (i.e. StoreItems) at any time.

Comment: Methods marked as synchronized don't lock on the method, they lock on the instance of the object in the case they are instances, and on the class if they are static. So they are already locking on the same object.

Comment: Thanks @RahulPrasad, is there any reason you prefer a synchronized block over declaring the methods synchronized?

Comment: As Mark pointed out in the above comment, by syncing methods we will be acquiring a lock on the complete instance object, this means that no other thread can use any synchronized method on this instance object while any synchronized method is being run by a thread. In the code snippet provided by you and the question posed, emphasis was put on the class member "StoreItems"; hence I suggested to use synchronized block on StoreItems & acquire a lock on it instead on an instance of StoreList. Also, it is better to use synchronized on private obj rather than on a method from security perspective.